# ZMQ (Jeromq) - Missing parameter in socket send documentation

Tags: java, sockets, zeromq, jeromq

I am currently trying to modify the simple hwclient/hwserver example to send a byte array with predefined size to the server. I have seen that basically the functionality is given in the following form:

```
public boolean send(byte[] data, int off, int length, int flags)
```

But there seems to be no documentation about the parameter `int off`. Can anyone tell be, what this parameter does?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would always be 0 if you want complete `byte[]` to be consumed if you want a partial consumption mention the offset of that Array index.

```
/**
         * Queues a message created from data, so it can be sent.
         *
         * @param data   the data to send.
         * @param off    the index of the first byte to be sent.
         * @param length the number of bytes to be sent.
         * @param flags  a combination (with + or |) of the flags defined below:
         *               </ul>
         * @return true when it has been queued on the socket and ØMQ has assumed responsibility for the message.
         * This does not indicate that the message has been transmitted to the network.
         */
        public boolean send(byte[] data, int off, int length, int flags)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask where you got this from?

Comment: https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq/blob/master/src/main/java/org/zeromq/ZMQ.java